# How to find a set of vectors spanning the solution space of $Ax=0$, where

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find a set of vectors spanning the solution space of $Ax=0$, where

[image]

Basically I have tried many times to solve it and my answer consistently comes in the following form:

$\pmatrix{1 \\ -1 \\-1\\0}$

While my book gives an answer of:

$\pmatrix{-1 \\-1\\1\\0}$

Comment: If a vector solves a homogeneous system then any scalar multiplication of that vector also solves it. Both vector are correct  or both are incorrect as the second one is the first multiplied by $\;-1\;$. In this case, I think they both are incorrect: none satisfies the second row.

Comment: @Joanpemo What? She wrote it in her original question... I simply TeX'ed it.

Comment: @Lovsovs Thank you. Perhaps the asker changed it before you texed it, or perhaps I missed some minus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\1&2&3&1\\2&1&3&1\\1&1&2&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&2&2&1\\0&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&\!\!-1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The general solution to the homogeneous system $\;A\vec x=\vec0\;$ is

$$x_4=0\;,\;\;x_1=x_2=-x_3\;\implies\;\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}t\\t\\\!\!-t\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\;;\;\;\;t\in\Bbb F\right\}$$

whatever the field $\;\Bbb F\;$ is. Thus, a particular non-zero solution, and also a basis for the solution space, is for example

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\!\!-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Do the following row-operations:

$$R_2:-R_4, \; R_3:-2R_1, \; R_4: -R_1, \; R_4:-R_3, \; R_3: -R_2$$

which gives you 
$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$$
which means $x_1+x_3=0, x_2+x_3=0, x_4=0$. Letting $x_1=x_2=t$, we have $$x=\pmatrix{t \\ t \\ -t \\ 0} \rightarrow \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

solve the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+z=0\\
x+2y+3z+t=0\\
2x+y+3z+t=0\\
x+y+2z+t=0
\end{cases}
$$
note that you can find $z=-x$ from the first equation and solve for the first three only since the fourth equation is a linear combination.

You find that the solution is the space of vectors of the form $(y,y,-y,0)^T$

so the solution of your book is correct ($y=-1$).